# Accessing my own repo in conda environment python

Tags: python, package, conda, virtual-environment

I have been having some issues here with accessing a personal git repo when I'm in my conda environment.

I eventually need to get this working on windows and linux as well, but i will start with mac.
What I have done in Mac terminal:

```
bash Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
conda create -n myenv python=3
conda activate myenv
conda install matplotlib numpy pandas scipy pymysql

mkdir ~/git
cd ~/git

git clone "fake.mygit.lab.url"
username: enter
password: enter
```

With this my git gepo is in dir ~/git/my_fake_repo

Since i did this in the conda environment, i would expect that when I activate my python envrionment and runn python:

```
conda activate myenv
python
import my_custom_package
```

it should work, this is how I have this repository working on a linux machine someone else set. The problem is we change this repo ever so often for different projects and need it easily accessible to enveryone.
What I am getting when  i do `import my_custom_package` is `>>> import my_custom_package Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_custom_package'`

I have a feeling this will be an easy fix. But i can not find the answer anywhere. I have in the past insert this repo directly in the lib directory of that environment and that works but that is problematically not an option this time around.

Thanks for any help folks!

Comment: A solution that isn’t as simple as you may like it to be would be designing your code to work with pip. Pip will handle the issues your having now and future ones when your team collaborates and you want to test the library as a user would. As to why it isnt working now, it is a pathing issue. To be included within the environment the python ide must know where it is (in the same folder or be explicitly set up when initializing) or it should be installed using pip. Both options can become complex. Check https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/ for more info.

Comment: I breifed through this document. I will see if i can get this working using that info. Thanks @jack

Comment: Is anything done to the contents of the repo, after the clone? It's just a valid Python package/module?

Comment: so i found a way to do this. If you ```cd``` into the directory all the packages live, ```import my_custom_package``` works just fine. thanks for all the help.